# Error Updating Table Python

Tags: python, sqlite

**    My Code  **

```
    cur.execute('Update  stud  SET(fname,mname,lname,course,yns,radio,sy)VALUES("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s") where Studnum=="%s"'%(fname,mname,lname,course,yns,status,sy,studnum))
    con.commit()
```

The Error

```
    cur.execute('Update  stud SET(fname,mname,lname,course,yns,radio,sy)VALUES("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s") where Studnum=="%s"'%(fname,mname,lname,course,yns,status,sy,studnum))
```

sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Comment: you dont use SET keyword when you do it like this only use `SET field="value"` type updates

Comment: Studnum=="%s"'..who told you about the == operator in SQL?

Comment: @user2799617: Actually, [sqlite3 has no problem with `==`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html): "Equals can be either `=` or `==`."

Comment: [Here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) is the syntax of the `UPDATE` statement. [Here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/update.php) are some simple examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic SQL syntax problem. Here is how you should write your query:

```
q = '''
    UPDATE stud SET
        fname = ?,
        mname = ?,
        lname = ?,
        course = ?,
        yns = ?,
        radio = ?,
        sy = ?
     WHERE
        Studnum = ?'''

cur.execute(q, (fname,mname,lname,course,yns,status,sy,studnum))
```

I replaced your `%s` with `?`, this is how you should pass parameters to a query in Python.

These are called *parameterized queries* and doing it this way helps prevent SQL injection because you are not injecting values directly in the SQL query. Not only that, it will make sure the value is correctly escaped for the database type.

In Python, there is a standard way of dealing with all databases called the database api (DB API). The [wiki entry](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DbApiFaq) on wiki.python.org goes into more detail, and the [manual page for sqlite in Python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) also has some examples.

Comment: i try your code sir but this is the error 
cur.execute(q, (fname,mname,lname,course,yns,status,sy,studnum))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

Comment: I don't know hwy this was downvoted… But anyway, you're solving two problems at the same time, but only explaining one. You need to explain that he got the `UPDATE` syntax wrong, and _also_ explain using parameterized statements, as two separate problems.

Comment: Thanks Burhan Khalid, its working now. Thanks also for those who tried to help.

Answer (score -2):

Will this work?

```
cur.execute("Update  stud  SET(fname,mname,lname,course,yns,radio,sy)VALUES('{}}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}') where Studnum=='{}'".format(fname,mname,lname,course,yns,status,sy,studnum))
```

I don't know which db you working with MSSQL doesn't like double quotes.

Comment: He's using SQlite, not MSSQL.

Comment: And MSSQL has just as much of a problem with completely invalid `UPDATE` syntax as SQLite anyway.